FCM API v1 and deeplinks issue
After switching from fcm-legacy to fcm-api-v1 and everything seems to be working fine, I'm encountering an issue with deeplinks. When the app is in the foreground, it immediately closes upon receiving a notification. Nothing happens when the app is in the background, and I click on the push notification. The popup window of the push closes.
I'm sending the push notifications using a PHP code, and the app is a webview app. However, this should be fine since I had no problems with fcm-legacy. Everything worked perfectly then, but not with the new API.
Additionally, I'm using the following library: Google API PHP Client
What might be wrong with this code?
$push =  '{
    "message": {
        "token": "key",
        "notification": {
            "title": "fcm-api-v1",
            "body": "message"
        },
        "android": {
            "notification": {
                "click_action": "https://www.domain.de"
                }
        }
    }
}';


Reviewing and adjusting the code to use FCM API v1 instead of FCM Legacy.
Ensuring that the app configuration for deep linking is correct.
Checking the Firebase configuration to ensure everything is set up properly.
Checking for potential errors in the server application, especially in the PHP code.
Comparing results between FCM Legacy and FCM API v1 to identify differences.
Searching for similar issues in developer forums and Firebase and Google API documentation.

